# When I init a dag with a Variable param, it raises an Exception

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am using apache-airflow==1.10.0

I get errors that looks like this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "variable" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM variable
```

When I declare tasks like:

```
 from airflow.models import Variable
 dag = DAG('dag')
 PythonOperator('task_id', ratio=Variable.get('ratio'), dag=dag)
```

because I don't have a Variable table yet.  I get errors that don't affect anything, but how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5):

For Airflow<2.0, run `airflow upgradedb`. For Airflow >= 2.0, run `airflow db upgrade`. It will create all the missing tables.

Comment: Can you add more details like what version of Airflow you are using?

Comment: added, so i run the resetdb and it errors, but it still works which is strange.

Comment: New versions is airflow db upgrade

Answer (score 2):

A workaround (in case `airflow upgradedb` doesn't work) is to do the following

1. Remove all the calls to variables in your DAGs code, you can do this by putting all of them into a function `set_variables()` and commenting it out
2. Start `airflow webserver` and create a dummy variable from the variable UI, this will create the Variable table
3. Now you can uncomment your `set_variables()`, your programmatic calls to variables will now work since you have the Variable table

Comment: yeah, that's not ideal though.  This adds some manual steps to the process every time i fire up a new instance, although I'm sure it works.